# Rails 5: Table name not being inferred through class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following rails model:

```
class Connection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :graph
  has_one :node, class_name: 'Person'
end
```

Each `connection.node` points to a `Person`.

I'd like to be able to find connections which point to particular people.

For example:

`Connection.joins(:nodes).where(node: {first_name: 'Jane'} )`

However this gives me the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "node"
LINE 1: SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections" WHERE "node"."firs...
                                                        ^
: SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections" WHERE "node"."first_name" = $1
```

I believe this is because its querying `nodes` instead of `people` as it needs to.

I've also tried `joins(:people)` but that gives an error of no association named `people` being found.

Any ideas how to achieve this, without having to rename the association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `joins`/`includes` you put the association name (singular (if `has_one`) or plural (if `has_many`)), into `where` clause you put the table name:

```
Connection.joins(:node).where(people: {first_name: 'Jane'} )
```

Comment: had to do `joins(:node)`, but it then worked. Thanks!

Comment: @ClickUpvote yea, because it's `has_one`, you're right!

Comment: The rules on when to plularize / not to plularize table names in where clauses, are also ambiguous.  E.g in the above query it requires plurals, but in another query it required me to use singular table name. `ImportedContact.joins(contact_info: :phones).where(contact_info: {phones: {phone: '123'} })`

Comment: @ClickUpvote in my understanding, in where clause you put **exact same** name of the table, that you have in database (and it does not matter, plural it or singular, despite the fact, that table naming convention says to use plural always AFAIK)

Comment: In the example I last gave, my table name is called `contact_infos`, but unless i provide it as `contact_info` in the where, i get `NoMethodError: undefined method _reflect_on_association' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @ClickUpvote wow, that's really interesting and surprising to know, really!